# .js file executes every time I click a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been googling the whole day for this... I'm still a beginner at html/css/php/javascript, so I probably have some rookie mistakes, but that's why you guys are here to help me!
So, I have a dynamic website with a static template and dynamically loaded content. For example, when I click the "About Us" link, the template remains the same, but the content gets loaded from another .php file and printed out in a iframe in that same index, using the $_GET method. I'm using iframe so I don't affect the template layout. My problem is that my .js file with animations gets executed each time I click any of the navigation links, so it makes my wish to, for example, fade in the whole website once it's loaded impossible. Each time I click a link the entire website would dissapear and fade in again. I don't know did I use Google wrong, but I cannot find the solution to my problem. I only want that script to run once when the page is loaded, not whenever I click a link! Here are some parts of the code:

**Part of index.php:**

```
<?php 
    include('setup/setup.php');
?>

<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="wrapOverall">
    <div class="header">Logo, language buttons etc.</div>
    <div class="wrapMainNav">Main navigation (Home, About us etc.)</div>
    <div class="content">
        <iframe src=<?php echo "content_$language/$pg.php"; ?> frameborder="0" style="width:951px; height:486px;">aaa</iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

where "content_$language" is the folder from which I get the file, and "$pg.php" is the file itself.

**The setup.php file:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if($_GET['page'] == '')
{
    $pg = 'naslovna';
}   
else
{
    $pg = $_GET['page'];
}

if($_GET['lang'] == '')
{
    $language = 'cro';
}   
else
{
    $language = $_GET['lang'];
}
?>
```

**The javascript.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapOverall").hide(); //Hide the website
    $("html").css("visibility", "visible");
    var bg = new Image();
    bg.src = "images/background.jpg";
    bg.onload = function(){ //Load the background image
        $("html").css("background-image", "url(images/background.jpg)");
        $("html").css("background-repeat","no-repeat");             
        $("html").css("background-attachment", "fixed");
        $("html").css("background-position", "center");

        $(".wrapOverall").fadeIn(1000); //Fade in the site
        $(".content").animate({height:'468px'},1000); //Animate content loading 
    }
});
```

That's about it, if you guys think you need more code I can send it.

Comment: Just a note, you can use a javascript framework like backbone (http://backbonejs.org/) to achieve this functionality without rolling your own solutions/using iframes.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: Angularjs is another one to check out ;)
I personally have experience with both backbone and angular and find angular is easier to do 'right'.

Comment: I'm in web development only for like a month or so, and I always learn stuff the hard way 'cause no one tells me about these awesome plugins. xD

Answer (score 2):

Each time you click a link, and the URL changes, the browser makes a `GET` request to the server for that page. PHP will return the page and the browser will reload it, even if it's 95% the same as the last page you were on. It'll re-render the DOM and hence the `$(document).ready` event will fire again.

What you're looking to do is to refresh a part of the page **without** making a GET request to the server for the whole page. To do this you need to use AJAX.

One of the simplest ways to do this is using jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method (click for documentation).

Have a look at the documentation and try a simple example, hopefully that will get you started.

**NOTE**: as has been mentioned already in the comments, there are plenty of frameworks that try to make achieving this functionality easier. Take a look at backbone.js, angularjs and ember.js to name a few. They also add a lot more, so depending on what you're trying to do, might be overkill, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Ed, u're a life saver. Thanks for explaining me this stuff, I'll try it and come back with feedback. It's strange how I couldn't Google my way out of this... I did see the load() method in the API documentation, but it didn't cross my mind that it has anything to do with the solution to my problem. xD BRB!

Answer (score 0):

Since your javascript is included in every page, it runs each time the page loads, and therefore hides and then shows the whole page. You should exclude it when loading other pages.

Comment: So my index.php reloads each time I click a link? I thought that it always stays the same, and that only the content changes. How can I exclude it from other pages when it doesn't exist there? It's only in index.php

Comment: Yes, PHP scripts run through from the beginning on each page load.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the the iframe content with ajax ? That way the php will be called in the same time than your js functions.

Comment: I didn't try that, since I don't know anything about Ajax. =( Will that solve my problem?

Comment: Yes you could try this 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.content').load('setup/setup.php').show();
});
Let me know if it works :)